# Searching for a text in some xib file in iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, xib, nib

I just wanted to know if there is any way of searching some specific text in form of UILabel, UITextField, or UITextView (only for those for which there are no IBOutlets created and text is given directly in the xib itself) . For normal texts , these can always be searched in all the .h, .m files but dont know how to search in xibs. Do we have to open manually each of the xib?

Answer (score 2):

run following command on **Terminal**

```
grep -i -r --include=*.xib "text you want to search" /path of your project
```

we can't search some text in .xib file using xcode. but we can search text in .xib file using above command with terminal.